# Using async middleware functions with swagger node project

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, swagger

I have generated an app using **swagger-node** (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node).

The automatic swagger router is not recognizing controller middleware functions with an async prefix. I have to use Promises inside middlewares.

**Is there a way to use async in the middlewares which are listed in swagger.yaml ?**

in swagger.yaml:

```
paths:
  '/positions/{positionId}':
    x-swagger-router-controller: controller
    get:
      description: some description
      operationId: getPosition
```

in controllers/controller.js

```
module.exports.getPosition = function(request, response) {
    const positionId = request.swagger.params.positionId.value;
    try {
        someModel.getPosition(positionId)
            .then(function() {
                return response.status(200).json();
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                return response.status(500).json();
            });
    } catch(error) {
        return response.status(500).json();
    }
};
```

and I would like to write:

```
module.exports.getPosition = async function(request, response) {
    const positionId = request.swagger.params.positionId.value;
    try {
        await someModel.getPosition(positionId);
        return response.status(200).json();
    } catch(error) {
        return response.status(500).json();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of the `swagger-node-runner` package (see [here](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/issues/443)) :

> they need to  they'd need to update their code to use the latest
>   release of `swagger-tools`.

I fixed that by :

First, installing the `0.10.3` version of `swagger-tools` in the project :

```
npm install --save swagger-tools@0.10.3
```

Then, changing the dependency of `swagger-node-runner` manually in the `node_modules/swagger-node-runner/package.json` file, like :

```
[...]
    "dependencies": {
        "bagpipes": "^0.0.6",
        "config": "^1.16.0",
        "cors": "^2.5.3",
        "debug": "^2.1.3",
        "js-yaml": "^3.3.0",
        "lodash": "^3.6.0",
        "swagger-tools": "^0.10.3"
    },
[...]
```

Answer (score -1):

For you to use the wait, you are using async in the creation of the function, it follows:

```js
module.exports.getPosition =  async function(request, response) {
    const positionId = request.swagger.params.positionId.value;
    try {
        await someModel.getPosition(positionId);
        return response.status(200).json();
    } catch(error) {
        return response.status(500).json();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the missing async, although I am specifically asking about using async await in the swagger-node.